# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. {% csrf_token %} in django python3 html

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to do a log in in django/python.

I have this in my views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def Principal(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method != 'GET':
        context = {
            'title': '405 Method Not Allowed',
        }


    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        logged_q = 'Logged in as '+ request.user.username
        logged = True
    else:
        logged_q = 'Not logged in.'
        logged = False

    print (logged_q)

    top_aparcamientos = Aparcamiento.objects.all()
    #top_aparcamientos = Comentario.objects.all().order_by('-aparcamiento__id').unique()[:5]
    pagina_list = Pagina.objects.all()       

    context['top_aparcamientos'] = top_aparcamientos
    context['pagina_list'] = pagina_list
    usuario = request.user.username
    context = {
      'usuario' : usuario,
      'logged' : logged
    }


    return render_to_response('index.html', context
```

So, for do my template, I take the variable logged in my base.html like that:

```
{% if logged %}
    <div class ="container_corner">
        <div class="topright">
            <span id="corner_message"><strong>Bienvenido,</strong>&nbsp<span class="oblicuo">{{usuario}}</span></span>
            <a href='logout/'><button id="logged"type="submit">Salir</button></a><br>
        </div>
    </div> {% else %}
    <form id="login_form" action="login/" method ="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="id_username"><span class="login_fields">Nick: </span></label> <input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text" />
        <label for="id_password"><span class="login_fields">Contraseña: </span></label> <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form> {% endif %}
```

But it gives me this error when I try to log in:

```
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Help Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

---

Do I need anymore `{% csrf_token %}`? Where?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the code for the view that handles the login form submission? (i.e. the view for the `login/` url) Are you using the Django authentication views?

Comment: '{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">zzz</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}'

Comment: That is the template code, what is the view code? Also, you can edit your question using the little `edit` link beneath your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, the views.py code is the first one!

Comment: That view is the one that renders the form, it doesn't look like that view handles the form POST.

Comment: what are you trying to do? if a user is logged in the form wont show? right? and where is your form validation process??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  {% csrf_token %}, you can probably use

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token }}' />
```

Or you can also use {{ csrf_input }}.

```
<form action="login/" method="post">{{ csrf_input }}
```